# MailApp.SendEmail function simply stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple Google App Script designed to send an email every day. It was working fine until a couple of days ago. Then it just stopped sending the email. I ran the script and logged the variables. All variables returned as expected, but no email was sent. Here's the script:

```
    MailApp.sendEmail({
       to: emailToAddress, 
       subject: emailsubject, 
       htmlBody: emailmessage,
       cc: ccemails,
       name: senderName
    })
```

Is there any reason why this script would run fine and then suddenly stop sending emails? There is no error message in the Execution Log: Execution started --> variable logging --> Execution completed.

**UPDATE**:

Based on some troubleshooting:

- The script fails when var emailsubject = ABC Fee Inbox (XYZ Asset Tracker)
- The script works when var emailsubject = ABC Fee Inbox - XYZ Asset Tracker
- The script works when var emailsubject = (Test)

Can anyone think of a reason for these differences in behavior?

Comment: MailApp does have a daily limit

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. I know I'm not anywhere close to a limit -- 2 or 3 emails a day.

Answer (score 2):

In documentation [on this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) there is an option to send all parameters inside the Object (as you have exactly done), but I would also try this

```
    MailApp.sendEmail(
       emailToAddress, 
       emailsubject, 
       '',
       {
       htmlBody: emailmessage,
       cc: ccemails,
       name: senderName
    })
```

I dont know why, but sometimes it can behave differently...

Comment: I tried trouble-shooting by changing the values of all the variables, one at a time. I narrowed it down to the Subject variable. My emailSubject variable had parentheses in it. When I removed the parentheses, my original code works. As does your variation. This was working fine about a week ago, so something seems to have changed with Google where it no longer likes "( )" in the Subject string.

Comment: Nice to hear your code works again. Thank you for sharing your experience.